# Developing with xcode beta 3 for iOS 6, can i send my application to App Store?

Tags: xcode, appstore-approval, beta, ios6

Now i'm developing an application for iphone with xcode beta 3. When i finished the application can i send it to approve to apple?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but when XCode 4.5 releases in the mac app store, then is it possible to sent it to apple.
You can develop it now in the beta and release it later.

Answer (score 2):

When you say 'xcode beta 3' you mean 'Xcode 4.5 DP3', right?

The answer is no, you cannot submit apps developed with preview versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Mountain Lion is released you can submit to the app store using Xcode 4.4. You won't be able to use Xcode 4.5 anything until iOS 6 is officially released.

That means that if you've updated your phone to iOS 6 beta, you won't be able to debug it with Xcode 4.4 (because it doesn't have the iOS 6 SDK). But you can still build with Xcode 4.4, and load the 4.4 built IPA onto your phone with iTunes or Xcode 4.5 if you need to run it. (Still you'll only be able to debug it when built and deployed from Xcode 4.5 on your iOS 6 beta device).

Answer (score 0):

You can send it now, using GM version